# VB.Net Double comparison after some additions

Tags: vb.net, comparison, double

I've faced a weird case with a double variable after adding some values to it.
The problem occurs when adding (0.2) to a double variable more than one time -I think it only happens with (0.2)- for example: consider this code:

```
Dim i As Double = 2
i = i + 0.2
MsgBox(i) '2.2
MsgBox(i > 2.2) 'False >> No problem
```

But if I add (0.2) more than one time:

```
Dim i As Double = 2
i = i + 0.2
i = i + 0.2
MsgBox(i) '2.4
Msgbox(i > 2.4) 'True >> !!!!
```

Also

```
Dim i As Double = 2
For x As Integer = 1 to 5
    i = i + 0.2
Next
MsgBox(i) '3
Msgbox(i > 3) 'True >> !!!!
```

I tried the same code with other values, I don't get this issue:

```
Dim i As Double = 2
i = i + 0.5
i = i + 0.5
MsgBox(i) '3
Msgbox(i > 3) 'False >> No problem
```

Anyone has an explanation for this??
Thank you

Comment: In short, floating point math is not exact, it just approximates reasonably well. You will find that exact comparisons on floats/doubles often don't match what you're expecting from exact math.

Comment: For example, typing in 2.4 in [this page](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) shows that the closest thing a double gets to 2.4 is (approximately) 2.4000000953674316.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the example 3 you would see that the result is actually `3.0000000000000009`.

The problem is in the rounding of a double.

If you change the data type decimal the problem is fixed:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim i As Decimal = 2

    For x As Integer = 1 To 5
        i = i + 0.2
    Next
    MsgBox(i) '3
    MsgBox(i > 3) 'False >> No problem

End Sub
```

[This is](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) about C# but, I guess, it the same thing for vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

This issue known as "[Accuracy Problems (Wikipedia Link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)"

> The fact that floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all
>   real numbers, and that floating-point operations **can not** precisely
>   represent true arithmetic operations, leads to many **surprising**
>   **situations**. This is related to the finite precision with which
>   computers generally represent numbers.